# Tensorflow get validation loss issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have confused ideas on how to calculate the validation loss in my model. I've a problem of classifying the pixels of the image.

So, after training, in validation statement, i can get my prediction image with this code:

```
output_image = sess.run(network,feed_dict={net_input:input_image})
```

But, if i run:

```
 cost , output_image  = sess.run([loss,network],feed_dict={net_input: input_image, net_output: output_image})
```

I get this exception: `Cannot feed value of shape (1, 480, 480, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 2)'`

I don't understand why, the shape of input and output images are the same (1, 480, 480, 3). 
What is the way to get the cost of validation image?

**EDIT**:
This is my code:

```
 net_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,None,None,3])
    net_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,None,None,num_classes]) 

    network, _ = model_builder.build_model(args.model, net_input=net_input, num_classes=num_classes, crop_width=args.crop_width, crop_height=args.crop_height)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=network, labels=net_output))

        opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=0.995).minimize(loss, var_list=[var for var in tf.trainable_variables()])

        saver=tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1000)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


        # Set random seed to make sure models are validated on the same validation images.
        # So you can compare the results of different models more intuitively.
        val_indices=random.sample(range(0,len(val_input_names)),num_vals)


        # Do the training here
        for epoch in range(args.epoch_start_i, args.num_epochs):

            current_losses = []

            # Equivalent to shuffling
            id_list = np.random.permutation( len(train_input_names) )

            num_iters = int(np.floor(len(id_list) / args.batch_size))

            #for i in range(num_iters):
            description_train = '[i]Train Epoch {:>2}/{}'.format(epoch + 1, args.num_epochs)
            for i in tqdm(range(num_iters), desc=description_train, unit='batch'):

                input_image_batch = []
                output_image_batch = []

                # Collect a batch of images
                for j in range(args.batch_size):
                    index = i*args.batch_size + j
                    id = id_list[index]
                    input_image = utils.load_image(train_input_names[id])
                    output_image = utils.load_image(train_output_names[id])

                    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                        input_image, output_image = data_augmentation(input_image, output_image)


                        # Prep the data. Make sure the labels are in one-hot format
                        input_image = np.float32(input_image) / 255.0
                        output_image = np.float32(helpers.one_hot_it(label=output_image, label_values=label_values))

                        input_image_batch.append(np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0))
                        output_image_batch.append(np.expand_dims(output_image, axis=0))

                if args.batch_size == 1:
                    input_image_batch = input_image_batch[0]
                    output_image_batch = output_image_batch[0]
                else:
                    input_image_batch = np.squeeze(np.stack(input_image_batch, axis=1))
                    output_image_batch = np.squeeze(np.stack(output_image_batch, axis=1))

                # Do the training
                _,current=sess.run([opt,loss],feed_dict={net_input:input_image_batch,net_output:output_image_batch})


                # Do the validation on a small set of validation images
                description_val = '[i]Validazione {:>2}/{}'.format(epoch + 1, args.num_epochs)
                loss_val = [];
                for ind in tqdm(val_indices, total=len(val_indices), desc=description_val, unit='img'):

                    input_image = np.expand_dims(np.float32(utils.load_image( val_input_names[ind] )[:args.crop_height, :args.crop_width]),axis=0)/255.0

                    output_image = np.expand_dims(np.float32(utils.load_image(val_output_names[ind])[:args.crop_height, :args.crop_width]), axis=0) / 255.0

                   #Do the validation
                    output_image =sess.run(network,feed_dict{net_input:input_image})
```

Comment: You need to provide more code. Obviously your placeholders last dimension is 2 and not 3 as you want it to be.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak Now you can see my code. As you can see i can get the training loss (It is the current variable,after comment line #Do the training), but in validation, i can't get the validation loss (after comment line #Do the validation)

Comment: The part where you define the offending placeholder is still missing.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak updated

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the number of classes (`num_classes`) is two in your case. So `output_image` you are feeding to `sess.run()` as `net_output` should have only two channels. But in your case, you have three channels and that's why you are getting this error.

Use `helpers.one_hot_it()` for getting a binary mask of your output image. You will have to expand dimension using `np.expand_dim()` to make it a batch of one image since the `network` accepts one batch at a time, not one image at a time.

You can make use of the following code snippet to get validation loss:

```
# Do the validation on a small set of validation images
description_val = '[i]Validazione {:>2}/{}'.format(epoch + 1, args.num_epochs)
loss_val = [];
for ind in tqdm(val_indices, total=len(val_indices), desc=description_val, unit='img'):
    input_image = np.expand_dims(np.float32(utils.load_image( val_input_names[ind] )[:args.crop_height, :args.crop_width]),axis=0)/255.0
    output_image = utils.load_image(val_output_names[ind])[:args.crop_height, :args.crop_width]
    output_one_hot = helpers.one_hot_it(output_image, label_values)

    #Do the validation
    output_image, loss_value = sess.run([network, loss], feed_dict={net_input: input_image, net_output: np.expand_dims(output_one_hot, axis=0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in  `net_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,None,None,num_classes])`. If this is the known classification of the image then it should be of the like (if those are already logits):

`net_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None, num_classes])`

To train your network you would do:

```
_, eval_loss = sess.run([opt, loss], feed_dict={net_input: input_image_batch, net_output:output_image_batch}})`
```

because you want to run the optimizer you have `opt` and because you want to monitor the loss you do `loss`.

To get the classification of an image you would do (after training):

`classified_images = sess.run([network], feed_dict={net_input: input_image_batch})`

Comment: I understood this concept. But this isn't my issue. Reffering to your code to get a classification of image, over this, i need to get the cost (loss). This will allow me to calculate validation loss, in this way i can measure overtiffing of my model. So, my code should be:  `classified_images, loss = sess.run([network], feed_dict={net_input: input_image_batch})`. 
How my call should be to get me the loss over the classification of image?

Comment: What is `net_output`? The class of the image? Then why is it 3 dimensional? I updated the answer to something which might help you.